# Jetty Startup issue: WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,null}

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, jetty

I´m trying to start a new project war with maven and spring into Spring Tool Suite IDE, I downloaded the project from Git Hub, the project was made on macs and I´m working in windows.

This is what I´m getting when I try to start the Jetty server:

```
2013-09-03 10:01:47.161:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.12.v20130726
2013-09-03 10:01:47.179:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor C:\Users\HP\Documents\workspace-sts-3.3.0.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps at interval 1
2013-09-03 10:01:47.183:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor C:\Users\HP\Documents\workspace-sts-3.3.0.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\contexts at interval 1
2013-09-03 10:01:47.187:INFO:oejd.DeploymentManager:Deployable added: C:\Users\HP\Documents\workspace-sts-3.3.0.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\contexts\moca-console.xml
2013-09-03 10:01:47.238:WARN:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:Web application not found C:\Users\HP\Documents\workspace-sts-3.3.0.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0/wtpwebapps/moca-console
2013-09-03 10:01:47.239:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,null},C:\Users\HP\Documents\workspace-sts-3.3.0.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0/wtpwebapps/moca-console
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\HP\Documents\workspace-sts-3.3.0.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0/wtpwebapps/moca-console
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.unpack(WebInfConfiguration.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.preConfigure(WebInfConfiguration.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1259)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1182)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:615)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)
2013-09-03 10:01:47.277:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

I have tried a bunch of possible solutions without success. Any suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: That looks strange: File not found exception: `C:\Users\HP\Documents\workspace-sts-3.3.0.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0/wtpwebapps/moca-console`

Comment: Could you, please, provide the github project, and tell us how do you run it ? mvn jett:run ? A jetty server from IDE ?

Answer (score 6):

It seems that your eclipse STS workspace is out of sync with the content published in the server. Try to clean the server, clean the working directory, clean all projects and Republish the project into the server.

If this does not work, try these steps to regenerate your eclipse workspace:

- close eclipse and do a maven clean install from the command line
- delete all eclipse related files: .project, .classpath and .settings
- reopen eclipse, and configure maven to use the same maven as the command line
- import the project using 'Import as Maven Project'
- scrap your Jetty and redownload a clean one
- Create a new Jetty server, point it to the new Jetty and add your application to it
- Republish the application and start the server

Answer (score 1):

Yep it looks like problem with plugins. So just close STS.
Deleting workspace  or plugin's is not good idea. It can create problem to other projects.

And follow these steps-

1. right click on project in project explorer.
2. select maven->update->tick all enable check box's->press ok
3. This will update all plugin's that are creating problem.

Best of Luck